# TikZ: How to use '\useasboundingbox' at end of content?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a Graph and some text below. How can I get only the red box as output?

[image]

```
\useasboundingbox  (Graph.north west) rectangle (Text.south east);
```

does not work.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]

\begin{scope}[local bounding box=Graph]
\draw[] (0,0) rectangle (4,2);
\end{scope}

\draw[] (1,0) -- (4,4);

\begin{scope}[local bounding box=Text]
\node[shift={(Graph.south west)}, anchor=north west, text width=4cm]{Some text here.}; 
\end{scope}

\draw[red] (Graph.north west) rectangle (Text.south east);
% \clip[] (Graph.north west) rectangle (Text.south east);
\useasboundingbox  (Graph.north west) rectangle (Text.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use an `overlay` option to draw the line: `\draw[overlay] (1,0) -- (4,4);`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of drawing the line diagonally first, it is enough to draw it last. Then cut the rectangle like you had the idea with `\clip`.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]

\begin{scope}[local bounding box=Graph]
\draw[blue] (0,0) rectangle (4,2);
\end{scope}



\begin{scope}[local bounding box=Text]
\node[shift={(Graph.south west)}, anchor=north west, text width=4cm]{Some text here.}; 
\end{scope}

\draw[red] (Graph.north west) rectangle (Text.south east);
 \clip[] (Graph.north west) rectangle (Text.south east);
%\useasboundingbox  (Graph.north west) rectangle (Text.south east);
\draw[] (1,0) -- (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```